# Bounds of the derivatives of a bounded analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f(z)$ is an anlytic bounded function in the closed  unit disc $|z| \leq 1$.We know from Cauchy's formula that

$$f^{(n)}(a) =\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}\,\mathrm dz
$$
Is it possible to find  a bound for the $nth$ derivative  $f^n(z)$ which does not involve $n?$ What about $f^n(z)$ as n goes to infinity?  Thanks for any responces/hints

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(z)=e^{2z}$. The $n$th  derivative at zero is $2^n$, so no bound independent of $n$ is possible.

Comment: Oh ,I am stupid!Thanks for the example!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1783051)

Comment: @KBS Thanks for your comment and for pointing out that readers might get confused and not realize this is an answer to the question. I believe this exactly answered their question, and it seems the OP thought so too:  The successive derivatives of $e^{2z}$ are not uniformly bounded, so one cannot get a bound independent of $n$ as they inquired about. I was not critiquing or asking for information, but giving a function that answered the question. I will edit my answer so it is clearer to other readers.